# How to append lists of strings into one list of string followed by ";"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got multiple lists (list1, list2, ...) which depends on a number of elements (they may change) in another listX -> len(listX)

How to append all of these lists of strings into one string followed by ";"?

list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = ['c', 'd']
...
listn = ['x', 'y']

the final string should look like: 'a;b;c;d;...;x;y'

Comment: I've added a "dynamic variable names" duplicate target. The moral of the story is that you should not create named variables like that. You should have a list of lists instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about collecting all the individual lists into a single list and then joining the individual items together.

Approach 1:- Collecting all the list and then joining them

```
intermidiate_list = list()
for i in range(len(mega_list)):
    intermidiate_list.extend(mega_list(i))

result = ";".join(intermidiate_list)
```

Here `mega_list` is the collection of all the lists you have. You can iterate over them by indexes and still make it work.

Approach 2:- Generating the list on the fly

```
result = str()
small_list = get_list()
while small_list:
    result += ";".join(small_list)
    small_list = get_list()
    if small_list and len(small_list) > 0:
        result += ";"
```

Now iterate the logic for all the list items you generate, in the end result will have the

Comment: not always I know how many lists I have and they are named list_1, list_2, list_n .. the question is how to loop for these lists

Comment: i tried something like: for i in range(len(listX)):
    list_of_all.append(wordListDE+str(i)).   but does not work @onlinejudge95

Comment: thanks, but how can i create this mega_list? @onlinejudge95

Comment: may I know in what way do you have the individual lists? Do you know beforehand how many of them are there?

Comment: it is webscraping and these lists of items depend on how many themes are present on a specific date, that is why the number is different and if len(theme) = 6 then I have six lists of items

Comment: So while scraping you can append these lists into the `mega_list`, and once scraping is complete then go around with the above logic

Comment: no, these lists don't correspond to anything with web scraping; it is my own input there

Comment: Simply put, create an empty `mega_list`, now whenever you get a single list just append it to the `mega_list` once you have all the items collected, then apply the join logic

Comment: the thing is that I would like to get it with loop by list index so that I dont append each of them manually